# How do I solve 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, laravel, ampps

I recently installed AMPPS 3.8 which has PHP 5.6 and 7.1 bundled in it.

I can't run the following Laravel command:

```
composer create-project –prefer-dist laravel/laravel LaravelWorks “5.5”
```

via command prompt, rather I'm getting the following error message:

> 'php: is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I didn't have this problem when I was using an earlier version (AMPPS 3.2).
Every solution I found on the web says I'm to check the PATH.
I've checked and it seems okay... I think:
 `C:\Ampps\php-5.6;C:\Ampps\php-7.1;C:\Ampps\php;`

I keep getting this error message even when I switch to PHP 5.6.

My OS is Windows 7 on 32bit architecture.

Comment: What is the output of `php --version`?

Comment: The output of php --version is the same error as above.

Comment: I ran "php --version" from "C:\Ampps\www" using command prompt

Comment: [installation of composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows)

Comment: I've uninstalled the previous version of Composer and the Ampps installation.

Comment: Now, I'm installing Ampps again. But this time in Program Folder

Comment: Before reinstallation, I cleared all registry issues

Comment: While installing Composer, i have this prompt:

Comment: Choose the command-line PHP you want to use: I intend to use both.How do I enter both paths?

Comment: Or is there a route to changing this later if I want to switch to PHP 7?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I finally figured out the problem. Composer's path to PHP had changed after I installed the new version of AMPPS. So composer presumed no PHP installation exists because it had no correct path to execute PHP. I didn't know composer's path to PHP would need updating on a new AMPPs installation.

So to everyone using an all-in-one local server package like AMPPS, ensure your "package manager" (in my case, Composer) has its PATH to  executing PHP scripts updated correctly.